# Open Source WinRT Library For MKV Files

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, ms-media-foundation, mkv

I'm trying to playback MKV Files in WinRT. Does anyone know of a library that has already been converted to work with WinRT? If not can anyone point me in the direction of a good library to get started with? I've not had any experience with Media-Foundation to date so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to play MKVs in WinRT?

Comment: Sadly not yet. I figure I'm going to have to write my own. Once I get version 1 in the AppStore I'll start writing some codec and container libraries if nothing has surfaced by then.

Comment: Maybe this one can help you: https://bitbucket.org/OlegZee/nebml

Answer (score -1):

Mkv is a container, *playing an mkv* it's a phrase that doesn't make much sense from both a coder prospective and user viewpoint, anyway you probably will not find a better Audio/Video library than [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: To clarify I'm trying to create an MFT that I can assign to a ByteStreamHandler.  I appreciate that doesn't cover all the codecs inside the container. I've found a WebM media foundation library but it won't let me add it as a reference to my winrt project and I'm struggling with converting it. I think I need a basic How-To to get me started if a full winrt library doesn't exist.

Comment: webm is built on top of mkv but in a stripped down version. I was going to try and get the webm library working and then add in any features I need that have been removed by the webm standard.

Comment: @Oli webm is a container designed for the VP8 codec, nothing to do with mkv, also even if you will be successful what are you going to do without a proper codec ? If you want to solve your first problem use ffmpeg, otherwise i'm not understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: http://www.webmproject.org/about/faq/ First paragraph confirms it's built on MKV. WinRT has a built in set of codecs but doesn't support the MKV container. If I can get a splitter working then a lot of the codecs inside an MKV file are already there ready to be used.

Comment: @Oli and where is the part that says that you can use webm for an mkv ? And how you think to solve the decoding phase ?

Comment: look at the paragraph that starts "Why create a new file type (.webm)? Why not use .mkv?"-You obviously then need to add the rest of the required stream types. Decoding is handled by the supported codecs in WinRT. Any unsupported codecs will require a MF Decoder. I'd much rather use an MKV MF library but Matroska themselves didn't know of one and suggested I extend WebM.

Comment: And to be clear, you can't use FFMPEG or similar because they're x86 code and not media foundation based. Same with Lav ETC. Any media foundation splitter that will split MKV needs to be native compiled C++ and signed for it to be addable to a project and usable and you'd need both a WinRT compiled version and a x86 and x64 version as well.  Once the Media Foundation splitter is done, then H264 etc inside of it will just work. It won't than play MPEG2, or Dolby TrueHD/DTS HD, but you'll get most other formats.